# Toggle to expand div (multiple)

Tags: javascript, toggle

I currently using this jQuery method of having div elements that are limited in size, but once clicked, expand to fit the length of the text:

```js
document.getElementById("toggle").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var s = document.getElementById("expandable").style;
  if (s.height)
    s.height = "";
  else
    s.height = "auto";

}
```

```css
#expandable {
  width: 20em;
  height: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<pre><code><p id="expandable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequat. Quis aute iure reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint obcaecat cupiditat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><a id="toggle">more</a></code></pre>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TbdgL/

However, I'm having trouble when trying to get a list of div rows all to expand. I think I have to adapt it so that both 'expandable' and 'toggle' become classes, but I can't seem to make it work. I'm new to this!

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You are right! A great way to write this functionality is the use of css classes!

I have forked your jsfiddle with a new implentation [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jleahy/x1vw7enr/1/).

Basically you can check to see if the element already has the class `expanded`, if the class is present on the element then remove it, else, add it!

The `expanded` class simply sets the element's `height` to `auto`.